EXcel VBA to copy URL from one sheet to another without the hyperlink
How can I copy & paste a url (e.g. to a website) from one excel sheet to another without also copying the format?
Any suggestions how to solve this?
The only way I have found it to work so far is:
Sheets("Input Form").Range("C17").Copy
Sheets("data").Range("N7").PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

However, that also transfers the formatting from the Input Sheet into my Data Table which I don't want to do.

Sheets("data").Range("N7").value = Sheets("Input Form").Range("C17").value also read How to avoid copy/paste

That does copy the text without formatting but also removes the URL.
So I end up with a cell that contains text.
Want I want though is to copy the link into a new cell but basically keep the destination formatting.

So you want the hyperlink but without the formatting (blue underlined?) You could e.g. change the "Link"-style.

I feel there should be an easier way to do this without saving every possible property of the destination cell (each border size, colour, font size, font colour, etc)..... surely pastespecial should have something?
My understanding of the question is to copy cell B3 to cell B5, but keep the formatting of cell B5.

Public Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        PasteLink .Range("B3"), .Range("B5")
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub PasteLink(SourceCell As Range, TargetCell As Range)
    
    'Add a temporary worksheet.
    Dim TmpSht As Worksheet
    Set TmpSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    
    'Copy the TargetCell format to the temp sheet.
    TargetCell.Copy
    TmpSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    
    'Copy the SourceCell to the TargetCell and then
    'copy the formatting back over.
    SourceCell.Copy Destination:=TargetCell
    TmpSht.Range("A1").Copy
    TargetCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    
    'Delete the Temp sheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TmpSht.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub



@David Just what I thought - I tried copying the value over as Ike did in his comment, and then copying the link over.... as soon as I created the link it changed the format to blue underlined.  There must be a way to create a hyperlink in a cell without upsetting the existing formatting.
